# How to get all possible combinations of different objects (list or str)

Tags: python, algorithm, path, combinatorics, python-itertools

it's more like a general question and I'm not sure if any algorithm exists for what I have in mind and if it exists what its called ...

let's say we have three objects (list)

```
["object", 1 , "this is object one"]
["object2", 2 , "this is object one"]
["object3", 3 , "this is object three"]
```

what I want to do now is create new lists with all possible combinations such as

```
["object2", 1 , "this is object three"]
["object1", 3 , "this is object two"]
```

and even future

```
 [3, "object2", "this is object one"]
 [1 , "this is object 2" , ] # last item removed as part of going for all combinations
```

so I'm looking for an algorithm to mix/combine/add/remove stuff in a logical framework.

I know python has but in itertools lib and combinations method but it doesn't seem to offer all combinations.

is there any known algorithm/lib for path and combinations between objects?

Thanks

Comment: For the first part, you can use `itertools.product(*zip(list1, list2, list3))`.  The second part is quite unclear and rather underspecified.

Comment: Have you tried itertools.product? It will give cross product of the lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to want *combinations*. You want [*Cartesian product*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and, probably, permutations (it's a little unclear from your description). For the Cartesian product, you need to do something like

```
itertools.product([
    ('object1', 'object2', 'object3'),
    (1, 2, 3),
    ('this is 1', 'this is 2', 'this is 3')
])
```

For the second part of your question, on every element of the list built by the previous example, you can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Comment: cartesian product and permutations are nice to know any other related algorithms?

Comment: @jdarap: can't think right now. read a tutorial on *combinatorics*.  there's a few variations on these ideas, how to select, combine and order things. seem easy, but they are quite tricky to get right.

Comment: @jdarap There are four that come with Python, which you can see in the "Combinatoric iterators" section of the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module docs. Mainly those are the ones you need—but sometimes you need variations on them (like permutations or combinations discounting repeated equal elements). Also, you often need to chain them up with non-combinatoric algorithms like `sorted`, `groupby`, or `unique`. Many of those other algorithms are also in `itertools`; you can find more in third-party libs `more_itertools` and `toolz`.

Comment: @jdarap Whether you want permutations depends on whether `["object1", 1, "this is 1"]` is considered different from `["1, "object1", "this is 1"]`. If the latter is not allowed, or is considered the same as the former, then you don't need permutations.

Comment: thanks, guys awesome. I'll do more research as I have some clue at least